# Wordpress - style.css doesn't seem to be updating on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

Whenever I update my `style.css` file in Wordpress, then update the file, I am able to see the change in Firefox or Safari, but never in Chrome, because for some reason Chrome has an old stylesheet.

I have tried restarting Chrome, and doing Ctrl+Shift+R and deleting the cache, but for some reason I keep having one image that doesn't show up, but on Safari it shows up fine.

For people who want to test: the site is https://newblueprint.staging.wpengine.com/ and scroll down toward the bottom and find the "OUR CAMPAIGNS" header. The yellow background should have an image on top of it, which shows up in Safari and Firefox, but not Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually chrome's display is correct. This image doesn't exist:

https://newblueprint.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/Blueprint/images/habit-burger-logo.jpg

I believe other browsers of yours have cached that image while chrome is rightfully not displaying it.

**Edit:**

I agree with hungerstar, the image has to be corrupted. The page, after all, does not return a `404`, but a broken image object.

**Edit 2:**

Opened the image in sublime and here's the actual problem:

[image]

Your image is actually a `.psd` that you either renamed to `.jpg` instead of properly converting or you're straight up trying to load a `.psd` into a webpage.

Comment: Same, doesn't display in any of my browsers.

Comment: That's very weird I was sure the image should exist. I'll check and update my question.

Comment: I stand corrected, Safari does show it. Firefox and Chrome do not.

Comment: I just checked the database, the file does indeed exist and i showing up as a real image and not an empty one, any other reasons?

Comment: Tested in Opera as well. So, Safari is the only one magically displaying this image. This is gonna be interesting.

Comment: It might be corrupted, if you can re-export or resource the image file.

Comment: Also, you didn't manually change the file extension hoping it would change it's filetype did you? i.e. renaming `file.png` to `file.jpg`.

Comment: @SergChernata nice catch. Looks like OP or, more likely, the client renamed the file extension from `.psd` to `.jpg`. Opened just fine in Photoshop for me when renaming extension from `.jpg` to `.psd`.

Comment: Yea I realized that right now, thanks for the help, I just took the image again and turned it into a png, working perfectly fine now.

Comment: @VishwaIyer you mean you exported/saved the image as a PNG.

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean, I opened the .psd in photoshop and then exported it as a png. I honestly don't remember manually changing the .psd to .jpg, but I guess I did by accident

Comment: Perhaps the client or whomever provided you with the image did that? It wouldn't be the first time I've had a client try and convert file types in such a manor. I've seen `.jpg => .png`, `.png => .jpg`, `.bmp => .jpg` etc. This is the first PSD to image file type I've seen, lol.

Answer (score 0):

This is the link of the image 
https://newblueprint.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/Blueprint/images/habit-burger-logo.jpg

and this is the link of the other images: 
https://newblueprint.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/Blueprint/images/Coca-Cola_logo_white.png

Do you see the difference? I've replaced the current image (with chrome inspection tool) with your current coco cola image to check and see if there was something wrong with the css but there wasn't. It's simple. You need to use a different image[image]

[image]

Comment: In a general sense you are correct, though **@Serg Chernata** has properly addressed the **why** it needs to be replaced.